# What does it mean to establish the state of the internal node in CMOS circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, inverter, cmos, vlsi

This is the NAND circuit and the 'int' is the internal node of the circuit.

[image]

It is seen that A = B= 0→ 1 gives the worst delay in the below table. What does it mean to establish the state of the internal node as stated in the text below.
It is not clear to me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switching speed of logic gates is determined by the driving strength of the transistors and the capacitances that are present on each node.

Only nodes where the voltage has to change are relevant.

If input A is switched from 1 to 0, the node "int" is initially at 0 and as M2 is switched off it remains at 0 since M1 stays on. The transistor M3 only has to charge the parasitics of node F.

If input B is switched from 1 to 0, M1 is switched off and M2 stays on. The node "int" is initially at 0 but has to be charged to about VDD-Vth. At the same time node F has to be charged as well so the transistor M4 has to charge two nodes, which makes this transition slower: "The state of the internal node has to be established".

Comment: So the internal node must be charged to VDD-Vth before charging the node F and this must be taken care by designing the inputs in such a way that the 'int' must be charged way before the circuit evaluates the actual output, so that there is no delay in output. Is it the inference?

Comment: When only B switches, then at first M2 connects the nodes F and "int". As the voltage on node F increases also the voltage at "int" has to increase. When "int" reaches VDD-Vth then M2 starts to turn off and only F needs to be charged.

Comment: Oh so it means that the 'int' node state has to be established along with the output node F and hence makes the Tplh slower. I wrongly assumed that we as designer must take the care of bringing the node 'int' to a stable state well before the evaluation of the actual output F. So the concept of establishing the state on internal node is implicit to the circuit.

Comment: Yes, you are right!